# Snowflake stored procedure Error Code 100183 Received unretryable http code

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, runtime-error, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a stored procedure in Snowflake which ran fine until today. Nothing has changed that we know of, and suddenly it starts to return error code 100183 (P0000) "Received unretryable http code". We can narrow it down to a specific query in the stored procedure, when we execute that outside the stored procedure it runs fine.

The query should insert all records from a view into a table:

```
'insert into dwh.' + rs.DWH_TABLE_NAME + 
    ' select * from dwh.vw_' + rs.DWH_TABLE_NAME + ';';
```

For some reason this works for table names starting with 'dim_' and not for 'fct_'

Any thoughts on how to approach this problem?

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well.  Mine exists as a SP that calls two other SPs.  If I run the code of the inner most SPs individually however it works fine, however calling them also fails.

Comment: I've already tried "execute as caller" and "execute as owner" explicitly, both with the original owner account as well as account admin privileges, no results :(

Comment: just as an update I have opened up a case for this and hopefully will get an update soon